# Using xpath on PHP: how to select first child?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have an XML structure like this one:

```
<layout>
    <pattern> ... </pattern>
    <row> ... </row>
</layout>
```

How can I select the first node of `<layout>` by its index, using XPath?

w3schools indicates syntax similar to `/bookstore/book[1]/title` , but then [says](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_examples.asp):

> There is a problem with this. The example above shows different results in IE and other browsers.
>
> IE5 and later has implemented that [0] should be the first node, but according to the W3C standard it should have been [1]!!
>
> A Workaround!
> To solve the [0] and [1] problem in IE5+, you can set the SelectionLanguage to XPath.

But that's client-specific. The PHP manual isn't very clear about this either.

Comment: What about trying? If `[1]` selects the first node, this is the way it works in PHP. There are only two possibilities so it is not impossible to do. Try and error :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Felix said: What about trying?

```
$l = new SimpleXMLElement('<layout>
  <pattern> ... </pattern> 
  <row> ... </row>  
</layout>');
foreach($l->xpath('/layout/*[1]') as $n) {// yeah yeah, it's only one....
  echo $n->getName();
}
```

prints `pattern`. (php 5.3.1/win32/php.net build)